# Quick launch menu - last 2 visited links stay "visited"

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, quick-launch, 2019, bug

a strange thing happened to us. In the left-menu, when you visit 2 links then they stay with property of ***"active"***, having blue font and grey background. It doesn't happen on another sites, only this one but only with some links, not all of them. Is it known bug or it's a problem on our side? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m not seeing this behavior in my SharePoint 2019 environment, so it should not be a bug.

Also [programmatically updating navigation elements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-on-modern-team-sites) is not yet supported for modern experience, so it should not be a customization error as well.

Looks like an isolated temporary issue on your side. Consider rebooting your machine and see if the issue will go away.

Comment: We 've already restarted a server but didn't help. Well I 've also noticed that it happens on all left navigations across the sharepoint, not just this one as I've thought. Navigations were created manually.

Comment: @sliziky Do you have publishing features activated? Does it make a difference if you are using just Quick Launch or Structural Navigation or others?